# How do I find all the combinations of n vectors that meet criteria in python

Tags: python, arrays, combinations, logical-operators, combinatorics

I wish to find combinations of the elements of n copies of a vector where the vector is simply: `np.arange(0,0.1,0.01)`. The combination is made up by selecting a single element from each vector.

I need the combinations to meet the criteria that each element within a combination is non-zero and the sum of the combinations = 1. I have the below function which works well:

```
# cols is a vector of length n.
def feasibility_test(row_in, cols):
    
    if np.around(np.sum(row_in), decimals = 2) == 1 and np.count_nonzero(row_in)>= len(cols):
        pass_test = True
    else:
        pass_test = False
    return pass_test
```

However for combinations of n= 6 or above meshgrid (code below) produces an array that overwhelms computer memory:

```
def generate_all_combos(range_in, cols):
    j = range_in
    if len(cols) == 4:
        new_array = np.array(np.meshgrid(j,j,j,j)).T.reshape(-1,len(cols))
    elif len(cols) == 5:
        new_array = np.array(np.meshgrid(j,j,j,j,j)).T.reshape(-1,len(cols))
    elif len(cols) == 6:
        new_array = np.array(np.meshgrid(j,j,j,j,j,j)).T.reshape(-1,len(cols))
    elif len(cols) == 7:
        new_array = np.array(np.meshgrid(j,j,j,j,j,j,j)).T.reshape(-1,len(cols))
        
    return new_array
```

The above code can be called with:

```
# Create range of values in parameter space of interest
underlying_range = [np.around(i, decimals=2) for i in np.arange(0,0.1,0.01)]

# Generate all possible combinations of col values
comb_array = generate_all_combos(underlying_range, cols)

# Check which combinations are feasible
feasible_combos_high_level = [row for row in comb_array if feasibility_test(row)]
```

Is there a way to get an array of feasible combinations without producing the entire range of combinations (the majority of which do not meet the feasibility test)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function that will only produce combinations that meet your criteria up front. Also, by using a generator, you are not immediately storing all the values in memory, so you can access them later on-demand:

```
import numpy as np
def combos(d, max_l, total_s, valid_f, rt = 0, c = []):
   if rt == total_s and len(c) == max_l:
      yield np.array(c)
   elif len(c) < max_l and rt < total_s:
      for i in filter(valid_f, d):
         for j in range(1, int(total_s/i)+1):
            if rt+(i*j) <= total_s and i not in c:
               yield from combos(d, max_l, total_s, valid_f, rt=rt+(i*j), c=c+([i]*j))

vals = np.arange(0,0.1,0.01)
result = combos(vals, len(cols), 1, lambda x: x > 0) #passing len(cols)
#printing first 100 valid combinations
for _ in range(100):
   print(next(result))
```

Comment: does this work for you? I get `:=` is invalid syntax and `_rt` is not defined. Something I am missing?

Comment: @user20862 `:=` is an assignment expression, available in versions >= Python3.8. Please see my recent edit, as I updated the solution to support versions <= Python3.8

Comment: Yes that works now. However it seems to produce vectors of differing lengths. Is there a way to set the length of the output vector as per the `len(cols)` switch in the original code?

Comment: unfortunately this does not find all the combinations and seems to be order dependent on cols. As a simple example: will get, for ``len(cols) = 3``, a combination of [0.4, 0.4, 0.2] but it will not produce [0.4, 0.2, 0.4]